# Why packer is returning the error "typing a boot command (code, down) 82, false" while trying to build a centos7 vm for Vsphere?

Tags: packer, vsphere, hcl, packer-builder, hashicorp-packer

Does anyone know how could I troubleshoot this booting packer error: Error running boot command: error typing a boot command (code, down) `82, false`: ServerFaultCode: Permission to perform this operation was denied.

I am trying to build a centos7 vm for Vsphere.
I am using vSphere Client version 6.7.0.46000 and packer 1.6.6 on macos.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the VM migrated during the boot process or right before the boot command was issued. If it was migrated as the boot command was getting passed it might have lost the console, causing the error you saw.